# Strange Error. Calling Oracle procedure from SQL Server does works fine but does not update output parameters

Tags: oracle, server

I posted some months ago this problem but no solution was found then.
It is very important for us to solve this !!!!

I call the following oracle procedure from SQLServer.
I have already verified that the procedure is indeed called and fired when called from sql server.
The oracle procedure has an output parameter.
Problem is that when i make the procedure call from sqlserver I dont get a value in the output parameter.
Instead I get a null value (in @outpp variable)

```
create or replace procedure ak_del_proc1(a1 number,
                                         a2 out number) is
begin
  a2 := 111;
end;

Declare @outpp varchar(50)
EXECUTE ('BEGIN ak_del_proc1(?, ?); END;', 9999, @outpp OUTPUT) 
AT MegaOracle;
Select @outpp
```

Thanks in advance.
Andreas

Comment: Normally the implicit conversation should happen as the Oracle procedure out parameter is number and while calling you are passing Varchar, but did you already tried by declaring as into `Declare @outpp int` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried all the declaring as int. Also I have tried other type of parameters without success....

Answer (score 0):

OK after a lot of hours, problem was solved!!

Here is the correct call from SQLServer:

```
declare @outpp int=2222;
EXECUTE ('BEGIN ak_del_proc1(?,?); END;', 999, @outpp OUTPUT) AT MegaOracle;
Select @outpp
```

The problem was that the parameter was not initialised.
When we gave a value to the @outpp, everything worked as expected.

```
declare @outpp int=2222;
```